# relational models not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I created the following Active Record Schema using migrations but the relationships don't correspond to the schema. I've tried resetting, dropping, creating and migrating but in Rails C if i create a User  u.User.create!(...), and then query u.groups or u.genres I get 'undefined method'

Thanks for your help

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180603211047) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "genres", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "tag"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_genres_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "genres_users", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.bigint "genre_id", null: false
  end

  create_table "groups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "name"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_groups_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "groups_users", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.bigint "group_id", null: false
  end

  create_table "playlists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "name"
    t.string "link"
    t.text "description"
    t.bigint "group_id"
    t.index ["group_id"], name: "index_playlists_on_group_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "name"
    t.string "token"
    t.date "birthday"
    t.string "link"
    t.string "playlistId"
    t.string "country"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "genres", "users"
  add_foreign_key "groups", "users"
  add_foreign_key "playlists", "groups"
end
```

here are the models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
    #before_action :authenticate_user!
    has_and_belongs_to_many :genres, :through => :genres_users
    has_and_belongs_to_many :groups, :through => :groups_users
    include Enumerable
end

class Genre < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :through => :genres_users
end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :through => :groups_users
    has_one :playlist
end

class Playlist < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :group
end
```

The relationship is that Groups have users, users have genres (favourite genres!), these are has and belongs to relationships through join tables (multiple genres per user and multiple groups per user). Every group has a playlist, and there will be multiple playlists

Comment: You actually have to define the associations in the model - ActiveRecord does not automatically deride them from the schema. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: To call u.groups or u.genres you have to declare the relationship in model User, have you declared a model User? There you'll have to declare :has_many groups.  On for Genre you will have to link with :has_one , for both of them you can  specify your :join_table

Answer (score 0):

[Edited after clarification from OP]

> The relationship is that Groups have users, users have genres (favourite genres!), these are has and belongs to relationships through join tables (multiple genres per user and multiple groups per user). Every group has a playlist, and there will be multiple playlists

First off, you don't need a `user_id` column on groups or genres as that's not how the setup should work.

```
class Genre < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :favorite_genres
  has_many :users, through: :favorite_genres
  [... other stuff]
end


class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :groups, through: :group_memberships

  has_many :favorite_genres
  has_many :users, through: :favorite_genres

  [... other stuff]
end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :group_memberships
  has_many :users, through: :group_memberships

  has_many :playlists
  [... other stuff]
end

class Playlist < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
end

class GroupMemberships < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
  [... other stuff]
end

class FavoriteGenres < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :genre
  [... other stuff]
end
```

So you'd drop the user_id column in groups. The connection happens in :group_memberships (the table formerly known as users_groups), which is a user_id, a group_id, and then you can have additional metadata columns as you need them (e.g. admin boolean/role, etc)
. This is called a "Has Many Through" relationship (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Likewise, a user's favorite genres is setup with a through relationship. So you'll have a separate database table AND model file for those through joins.

I don't think you need your `add_foreign_key` calls at all at this level, nor many of your indexes. You'll probably do more eager loading or possibly add indexes on the thorugh join tables and you'd do those like this in the schema:

```
t.index ["user_id", "genre_id"], name: "index_favorite_genres_on_user_id_and_genre_id"
```

Remember that `belongs_to` now creates a validation for that to be present in 5.x. You can override this by adding `optional: true` on that line in the model, e.g. `belongs_to :foo, optional: true`

So all that being said, here's your new schema:

```
create_table "genres", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "tag"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "groups", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "favorite_genres", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "user_id", null: false
  t.bigint "genre_id", null: false
end

create_table "groups_memberships", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "user_id", null: false
  t.bigint "group_id", null: false
end

create_table "playlists", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.string "name"
  t.string "link"
  t.text "description"
  t.bigint "group_id"
  t.index ["group_id"], name: "index_playlists_on_group_id"
end

create_table "users", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.string "email", default: "", null: false
  t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
  t.string "reset_password_token"
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
  t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
  t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
  t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
  t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
  t.string "name"
  t.string "token"
  t.date "birthday"
  t.string "link"
  t.string "playlistId"
  t.string "country"
  t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
end
```

Give that a whirl (I haven't built this in an app, so there may be some errors in the code) and you should now be able to do your console run:

```
u = User.create([values])
u.genres (should return nil until you create some relationships)
```

etc.

Comment: Ah okay. So Genres exists as a separate thing. No user_id on that table. I would do another has_many through for that called `favorites` or `genre_favorites`. You can do multiples this way as well. HABTM is something rarely used (I haven't seen it in an active app in years myself). Here's a longer explanation of why you want through over HABTM: http://blog.flatironschool.com/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/

Regardless, the "through" shouldn't be there for a habtm association.

Comment: Because you're fighting the Rails conventions. It's a pretty straight forward data model which will work as expected if you work in the standards of the framework. I'm going to edit my original answer to detail it out, as the comment form is limited for details.

Comment: Thanks!! : ) i actually just got my version working, though i can't explain how .. really appreciate your help will go over and tighten up!